# Doubly linked list with different dependencies

Tags: java, linked-list

I need to connect different `Task` with a double linked list and different `Dependencies` which affect a calculation for which I need the values of both `Task`:

```
public class Task {
    private List<Dependency> parents = new ArrayList<Dependency>();
    private List<Dependency> children = new ArrayList<Dependency>();

    //Uses the parents values and calls `calculateForwards` of the children
    public void calculateForwards() { .. }
    //Uses the children values and calls `calculateBackwards` of the children
    public void calculateBackwards() { .. }
}

public interface Dependency {
    Task getTask();
    void setForwards(Task t);
    void setBackwards(Task t);
    Dependency createCopy(Task t);
}


public class EA implements Dependency {
    private Task task;

    //............

    @Override
    public void setForwards(Task t) {
        if (t.getEarlyStart() < task.getEarlyFinish())
        t.setEarlyStart(task.getEarlyFinish());

        t.setEarlyFinish(t.getEarlyStart() + t.getDuration());
    }

    @Override
    public void setBackwards(Task t) {
        if (t.getLatestFinish() > task.getLatestStart())
        t.setLatestFinish(task.getLatestStart());

        t.setLatestStart(t.getLatestFinish() - t.getDuration());
    }

    //............

 }
```

For now dependencies are created with the `Task` it points to and added to the children list. Then a copy of the dependency is created that points to the original task and added to the parent list of the child:

```
public void addChild(Dependency r) {
    children.add(r);
    r.getTask().addParent(r.createCopy(this));
}

private void addParent(Dependency r) {
    parents.add(r);
}
```

As you can see this data structure does the job, but very ugly in my eyes. How can I solve this more elegantly?

- [Task.java](https://gist.github.com/Savaron/fc3c6667c55b17981f68#file-task-java),
- [Dependency.java](https://gist.github.com/Savaron/fc3c6667c55b17981f68#file-dependency-java),
- [EA.java (implements Dependency)](https://gist.github.com/Savaron/fc3c6667c55b17981f68#file-ea-java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Task` depends on `Dependency` (not very troubling in itself) :

```
public class Task {
    private List<Dependency> parents = new ArrayList<Dependency>();
```

Also `Dependency` depends on concrete class `Task` (somewhat more troubling):

```
public interface Dependency {
    Task getTask();
```

Although dependency cycles of size 2 are not intrinsically a problem, in this case interface `Dependency` is pretty much useless, [if we look at the implementation, which is a hybrid holder and wrapper for `Task`]. Too generic a name and getters and setters on the interface are also signs that this interface does not pull its weight.

If the problem model is a graph it is expected that class that represents the node of that graph should be depend on itself. Dependency cycles of 1 is generally better than 2.

### My Suggestion

The only methods that contain logic in the implementation of `Dependency` is `setBackwards` and `setForwards`. But when we read them we see that they manipulate the insides of `Task`, and therefore should be moved into that class. After the said move you can remove `Dependency` and `EA`, and directly use `Task` instead.

Comment: So I need to move the graph stuff into Dependency?

Comment: @Sven I appended my suggestion to the answer. I suggest you should get rid of `Dependency` and `EA`. As for moving graph stuff elsewhere, it seems reasonable. I imagine a `TaskNode` class, which *has a* `Task`, having links to other `TaskNode`s makes sense.